# PyQT: Silly QPainter.drawEllipse

Tags: python, pyqt, qpainter

The longer I stare at the code, the less I understand it, but the funnier it gets. In one case QPainter draws the circles, in another it does not.

My problem is that if it is successful, QPainter **does not** draw. If, on the other hand, it was not successful, it **does** draw. What I actually want to achieve is changing the color depending on the state. This rather ugly code is for illustration. Moving the QP.begin() outside the loop or having just a single drawEllipse() in the end outside the if-clause does not do any difference.

```
def paintEvent(self, e):
        # compute here diameter, offsets, etc. but nothing qt related
        for i in xrange(5):
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            x_offset += 5
            if self.isSuccessful():
                print "Successful"
                painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0,255,0))
                painter.drawEllipse(x_offset, y_offset, diameter, diameter)
            else:
                print "Not yet"
                painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0,0,255))
                painter.drawEllipse(x_offset, y_offset, diameter, diameter)
            painter.end()
```

Can someone tell me why in one case the ellipse is actually painted and in the other it is not?

The output is:

> ...
>   Not yet
>   Not yet
>   Not yet
>   Not yet
>   Not yet
>   Successfull
>   Successfull
>   Successfull
>   Successfull
>   Successfull
>   ...

It does not matter whether the ellipse has been drawn before or not. In case I comment the drawEllipse() in the "not yet"-case, no circle is drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the source of the paintEvent I created. The paintEvent was called when a containing textbox got focus. But the update region for the event only included the text box, which actually does make sense but I did not know. So paintEvent was called, but the update region did not include the circles.

I circumvented the problem now by calling the update-method for the whole widget, which solves the problem.